# html email not showing correctly in iphones

Tags: html, ios, iphone, email, html-email

I'm using php to send out an invite email for my app. The html for the email is roughly

```
<html>
<body>
   <div style="border:7px solid #79973f; width: 527px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;border-radius:7px;">
     <div style="width:440px; margin:20px auto 50px auto;">
        <p style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;"></p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This layout shows up perfectly in gmail but the width and margins are not correctly shown in the iPhone Mail app. Help?

Comment: iPhones support media queries for responsive e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're explicitly setting the width in the HTML. What you should do is use the css property `max-width` to assign the maximum width you want it to display, but it will be shrunk by a smaller display (i.e. on an iPhone)

Comment: don't you mean min-width?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, you just have to specify min-width of the style

Answer (score 0):

You need to make HTML emails in tabels not divs, alot of clients dosnt support that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work on your iPhone after the comment you made... But this surely will not work on a lot of other mail clients. Amongst which a few Outlook-clients.

Look at this: http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/